# How to prevent JSON exception, when sending POST with empty string to endpoint in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

today I found that, when I send **POST** with `""` (empty string) it throws exception.

```
public IActionResult SendRegistrationLink([FromBody] JObject json) {
  ...
}
```

Exception:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

lambda_method(Closure , object , object[] )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(object target, object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I know, that it is because of using `JObject`. Should I use very specific model or just use `Object` and then deserialize it? Or do you have a better solution? I'm open for any suggestion.

And of course my CURL:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i http://localhost:5001/api/something --data '""'
```

Comment: Always bind to a strong type, not something like `JObject` and definitely not `Object`. Create a class that represents the request body and use that.

Comment: send an empty json object which could be {}

Comment: @ChrisPratt So I should use strong type like `string`, if I pass one argument and some model (class) for more than one argument. Am I right?

Comment: You should use a class in either case, ideally. JSON is always an object (**J**ava**S**cript _**O**bject_ **N**otation).

Comment: Ok, thanks again @ChrisPratt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with ASP.NET Core always use strong types. Never use a type like `JObject` in that case. Create a model for your needs. Something like:

```
public class yourType
{
   private int x; 
   private string xyz; // you know what I mean.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but the downvote was likely because your answer doesn't strictly answer the question. It's good advice, but not an answer. As a result, it belongs as a comment, not an answer, which is actually why I said the same thing 5 minutes before you in the comments.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Ohhh actually didn't saw that.. o.O